# Can't get ListLinePlot to work on simple databin data

Tags: plotting, databin

I do the following:

```
b=Values[Databin["BX8vj6ow"]]
```

> ```
> {10,20,30}
> ```

Then I do

```
ListLinePlot[b]
```

I get an empty plot.

Then I do

```
a={10,20,30}
ListLinePlot[a]
```

I get the expected plot.

I have struggled with the Databins.  I can put data in and get
it out, but no matter what I do I cannot act on the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values in the `Databin` are strings.

```
b // InputForm
(* {"10", "20", "30"} *)
```

Try this

```
ListLinePlot[ToExpression[b]]
```